# How to emit data from background process to Flask-SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

> emitted data from different process to socketio but not working

I created Flask App in which I am using `Flask-SocketIO` framework. The code for flask app is below:

```
from web import create_app, socketio

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run()
```

I am running this using `flask run` command.
But I have another python script in which I am importing `socketio` and want to emit data to client's browser.

```
# cli-script.py
import time
from web import socketio

def demo():
    while 1:
        socketio.emit('my-event', ("My Data"))
        time.sleep(10)

demo()
```

My flask application folder structure looks like this:

```
/-
  web
    __init__.py
    code.py
  web-script.py
  cli-script.py
```

and I am running two python processes:

```
flask run 
python cli-script.py
```

Why this doesn't work ?